# In the jaxb-ri samples the ant script gives some xjc error which I do not understand

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I downloaded jaxb from `https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2`, did `mvn clean install` and went to modify-marshal in the target/stage/samples directory. There I did `ant`, and the Java classes were created, but then ant stops because there is some error which I do not understand:

```
compile:
     [echo] Compiling the schema...
      [xjc] C:\Users\ervelden\java\jaxb-v2\jaxb-ri\bundles\ri\target\stage\jaxb-ri\samples\modify-marshal\gen-src\primer.po is not found and thus excluded from the dependency check
      [xjc] Compiling file:/C:/Users/ervelden/java/jaxb-v2/jaxb-ri/bundles/ri/target/stage/jaxb-ri/samples/modify-marshal/po.xsd
      [xjc] Writing output to C:\Users\ervelden\java\jaxb-v2\jaxb-ri\bundles\ri\target\stage\jaxb-ri\samples\modify-marshal\gen-src
      [xjc] Command invoked: xjc"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\java.exe"
      [xjc] failure in the XJC task. Use the Ant -verbose switch for more details
```

In the ant build.xml there is:

```
   <xjc schema="po.xsd" package="primer.po" destdir="gen-src">
      <produces dir="gen-src/primer.po" includes="**/*.java" />
    </xjc>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I have downloaded jaxb-ri-2.3.0.zip and I have made a tiny build.xml file. No success.

Comment: @BOC I added fork="true" in the <xjc ...>, so <xjc schema=... package=... ... fork="true">

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly.